# 日本語に違和感: 「未回答」の質問

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

以下の画像のように質問の一覧で「未回答」を選択すると、未回答の質問として一覧が表示されますが、実際には回答が付いている質問も一覧に表示されるため、「未回答」という言葉に違和感がありました。
[image: 未回答の質問]

また質問の一覧のページ下部には以下のようなリンクがありますが、リンク先は「未回答」質問の一覧になっています。

> 質問をもっと見るには、全ての質問のリストか人気タグ一覧をご覧ください。[未解決の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)では回答を募集中です。

「未回答」ではなくリンクの文章のように「未解決」の方が良いと思いますが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: 実は同じunansweredでも場所によって「回答がない質問」「upvote/acceptされた回答がない質問」と定義がぶれているのが[英語版でも指摘されています](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145033/286934)。翻訳は一つの英文に一つの日本語訳なので統一しないといけませんが、まあ両方とも"未解決"にしてしまってもいいでしょうね...。

Comment: なるほど…。英語のunansweredに「答えが出ていない->解決していない」みたいなニュアンスがあるのかなと思っていました。英語でも定義がぶれてしまっているのですね。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

コメントにも書きましたが、これに関しては英語版でも、場所によって「回答がない質問」「upvote/acceptされた回答がない質問」とunansweredの意味合いがぶれているのが[指摘されています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145033/286934)。

現在の翻訳ワークフローの都合上、場所を問わず同じ英文には同じ日本語訳をあてなければいけないので、翻訳でこの二つを書き分けるのは難しいです。とはいえ「未解決の質問」には未回答もとい回答のない質問が含まれますから、**明らかに回答のない質問のみを指している文章以外は「未解決」とする**という方針でいいのかなと思います。

数日待って他に意見/反論がなければTransifexに反映しようと思います。

Comment: 次回のビルドに適用されます（未回答→未解決）