# 回答の承認を行わないユーザに知らせる方法は？

Tags: 討議, サポート

たまにコミュニティが上げてくる質問を見ていると
解決していて、承認がされていない質問を見かけます。

そういったユーザの質問履歴を見ると過去1度も承認をされたことが無いユーザもいます。

大体はコメントなどで"承認を行うように"誘導したりしているのですが、
既にコメントで通知済みで、「同じことを何度もコメントに書くのはなぁ…」と考えました。

そこで下記の疑問があります。
・こういったユーザにコメント以外で承認するように通知出来るか？
(仕組みがあったような気もしますが探せなかったので…あるんですかね？)
・コメントで既に誘導している中、もう一度誘導する必要はある？してもいい？
(1ヶ月以上コメントから開いていたりとか……)

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: related: [回答の承認をしない、または承認という機能を知らないユーザーが多い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1784/8000)

Comment: 少し関連: [「承認」は言葉を変えてはどうか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1852/%E6%89%BF%E8%AA%8D-%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

個人的には、一度「承認」をお願いしたユーザーさんには、何度も同じお願いをしなくてよいのではないかと思っています。回答を承認するかどうかは質問者さんの一存次第ですし、第三者から見て問題が解決しているように見えても、実はそうでないかもしれません。回答を承認するかしないかという選択肢も、質問者に与えられて良いのではないかと思っています。

[別のメタ質問のjmacさんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1789/19110)にあるように、第三者がすべきなのは承認を何回も催促することではなく、upvoteすることではないでしょうか。回答の価値は「承認」だけで決まるものではありません。また、「未解決」な質問が気になる方も、良いと思う回答に投票し、もしそれがプラスの投票を貰っていれば「承認」なしに「未解決」から外されるようです。

回答者が安心したり信用度を得たりしたいがために「承認」をもっと推進したい、というユーザーさんもいるかもしれませんが、その場合は、[このメタ質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1852/%E6%89%BF%E8%AA%8D-%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)にあるように、まずは「承認」という言葉から考える必要があるのかもしれません。

Comment: まず同じお願いをしたところで結局同じことの繰り返しになるので私としても記載されている内容には同意します。ただ、Upvoteされたら消えるというのは理解しているのですが、`承認されていない質問を消したいならUpvoteする`というスタンスに疑問を感じます。例えば質問内容を見てソレが良回答なのかどうなのか一見では分からない場合もあります。分かる人がすれば良いというのもありますが、浮上する質問が煩わしいのもあり、それにより"+1"が軽くなってしまうのであれば微妙かなと感じました。

Comment: そもそも論として、もし承認されている回答が無く、かつ自分が見てもupvoteしたくなる回答が無いのであれば、それはまさしく未解決な質問なのではないでしょうか。無理にどれか1つupvoteすべきだ、とまでは言いたくないですね……。

Comment: 閲覧者が判断できない(Upvote対象が無い)のが未解決の質問なのでしょうか？私は質問者の問題が解決出来ていないものが未解決の質問かと思います。結局のところ、質問者以外が未解決を解決だと判断は出来ないのではないでしょうか？そうなると、やはり質問者本人に承認いただきたいですね。

Comment: @Myaku  誰にとって未解決なものを「未解決」と読んでいるのか、は確かに問題となりそうです。あれ、でもそうなると、1つでもupvoteされてる回答があれば「未解決」から外されるってのは仕組みとして少しおかしいってことになっちゃうんでしょうか。うーん、難しいですね。

Comment: @Myaku すっかり忘れていましたが、そういえば「未解決」は英語では "unanswered" で、数カ月前に訳を「未回答」から直したのでした。だから今まで主語が気にならなかったのかもしれません。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2414/